# Issue with CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync while taking snap frequantly using winrt

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a problem with `CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync` while i am taking a snap frequently in Win Rt(Surface), during the capture if its crossed more then 13 snap the `CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync` function did not return any value.

hence the surface restarting because of this issue, can any one know the fix about it, it would be more helpful,

Answer (score 1):

The following works around the issue where the Surface RT does not consistently capture video frames:

```
await mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imageProperties, file);
```

It may take a little extra time to stop/start the preview before each frame. This was my first shot at a workaround so there might be better ways.